# Linuxbrew: configure: error: could not find a working compiler

Tags: gcc, linuxbrew

When executing `brew install` on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (xenial) I am getting the following error which breaks each install:

```
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=64
checking compiler gcc-13  ... no
checking ABI=x32
checking compiler gcc-13  ... no
checking ABI=32
checking compiler gcc-13  ... no
configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a test file by executing: `echo 'int main(){}' > dummy.c`
2. Run `gcc-13 dummy.c` which will give the error below (please note that `gcc dummy.c` can work just fine)

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/liblto_plugin.so: error loading plugin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/liblto_plugin.so)
```

3. Run `brew link --force binutils`

```
Linking /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/binutils/2.40.reinstall... 86 symlinks created.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/binutils/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

4. Then as recommended run:

```
echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/binutils/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

5. You can now optionally check your PATH by running: `echo $PATH`
6. Run `brew config`

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 4.0.28
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 2b4cfb033757b63ab0b128d01c58db76480956f9
Last commit: 7 days ago
Core tap JSON: 13 Jul 21:39 UTC
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: set
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 1
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.10 => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.10_1/bin/ruby
CPU: single-core 64-bit haswell
Clang: N/A
Git: 2.7.4 => /usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.47.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-1160.80.1.vz7.191.4 x86_64 GNU/Linux
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (xenial)
Host glibc: 2.23
/usr/bin/gcc: 5.4.0
/usr/bin/ruby: 2.3.1
glibc: N/A
gcc@11: N/A
gcc: N/A
xorg: N/A
```

7. Now `gcc-13 dummy.c` should give no error
8. And now the `brew install` should work without any error as well